# How to refresh a div content in JavaScript when the page has not loaded completely?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a small web page with a single div whose content needs to be updated periodically. The server sends JavaScript with a function that contains the new data to be updated in the div.  Here's the first part of the code that the server sends:

```
<html>
<head>
 <script>
  function bar() {
   document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = "0";
  }
</script>
 </head>

 <body onLoad="bar()">
 <div id="foo"></div>
 </body>
```

After a delay (2 seconds), the server sends in the remaining code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function bar() {
   document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = "1";
  }
</script>
</script>

</html>
```

The trouble is that I never see the div show "0" in it - the browser waits until the entire page is loaded, and straightaway displays "1" in the div. How do I get the div to show "0" in it while the server has not sent the entire page?

I am not looking at using any jQuery or AJAX code - please limit your answers to JavaScript only.

Comment: Why don't you set the content of foo without javascript to 0 when the server sends the html? After the page is loaded you could delete the innerHTML and set it to 1 with javascript.

Comment: I need the content of the div to keep changing as more JavaScript comes in from the server. The main problem was the browser was not rendering the page until all of it returned. Check out the accepted answer below for an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use `onload` -> that gets fired only after the whole page has completely loaded.

Also you have to add some more bytes to the first response, because most browsers only start incremental rendering of the page after a certain ammount of data being received.

This should work:

```
<html>
<head>
 <script>
  function bar(x) {
   document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = x;
  }
</script>
 </head>

 <body>
 <!-- AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA -->
 <div id="foo"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    bar(0);
 </script>
 </body>
```

--- DELAY ---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  bar(1);
</script>
</script>

</html>
```

Here is a working example in node.js:

```
var http=require('http');

var server=http.createServer(function(req,res){
    res.write('<html><head> <script>  function bar(x) {  document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = x;  }</script> </head> <body><!-- AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA --> <div id="foo"></div><script>bar(0);</script> </body>');
    setTimeout(function(){
        res.end('<script type="text/javascript">  bar(1); </script></html>');
    },2000);
});

server.listen(8080);
```

it first shows "0" then after 2 seconds "1"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's possible to do it the way you're trying. The browser will always wait till the page has fully loaded, so it will always wait till you send that second batch.

If you don't want to use AJAX or jQuery, you could try a hacky version to get what you want.

What you can do is specify a callback function on your page to populate the div with a parameter, so something like

```
callback = function(data) {
    document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = data;
}
```

Then, you set a timeout on your page to send a request to your server to dynamically load a javascript file that calls that function. So again:

```
myTimeout = function() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "http://myserver.com/mydynamicscript"; 
    document.getElementByTagName('head').appendChild(script);
}
setTimeout(myTimeout, 2000);
```

The script that you're loading can either be static, or some servlet/php file that returns a javascript file, i.e. it sets it's content-type header to "text/javascript".

In that script, you would then generate this:

```
callback("whatever I want to put in my div...");
```

Once that has been loaded, it will call the previous function you declared earlier, and load the content in that div.

It's effectively a hacky form of AJAX, but not AJAX.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I will go with the answer suggested below since it seems to fit my use case better.